# ExpressJS: Is the req.hostname property enough to use it as validator in terms of security againts a domain whitelist?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any other way to get the hostname in a stronger way?
http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.hostname

Answer (score 0):

The hostname property is the name of your own server. If you run your nodejs server behind a reverse proxy (nginx, maybe), you need to do a [little extra configuration](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname).

It tells you nothing useful about the browser or other program making requests to your server, though.

You may be thinking of `req.headers[referer]` instead. When your request comes from a browser, that's the URL of the page sending the request. But that's too easy to spoof with simple tools to be much use for detecting attackers.

Your best bet lies in proper authentication and hard to guess session cookies to validate requests to your server. [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) can also help with web services. Explaining all that is too much for a SO answer.

Comment: The domain whitelist is just another security layer in my web server. So I will really need to change it using CORS in order for this layer really gives value in terms of security.